# Compare two database entries and produce span class

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, joomla, content-management-system

I wonder if anyone could help me with this.

I have two fields in a database that are shown using:

1-`<?php echo JHTML::_('date', $row->created_date, 'd/m/Y'); ?>`

2-`<?php echo $row->delivery_date; ?>`

The first one, is written to the database as a full date with time, and as you can see above, I strip the output to only show the date. In the database it would appear as '2013-09-10 11:56:52'

The second is from a text entry form field, that has just text saved to the database in the format d/m/Y. In the database this appears as '19/09/2013'

Is there a way I can produce an if statement, that will add a span and class tag around the 2nd line if this condition is true:

**"If the $row->delivery_date is within 21 days after (and including)
     $row->created_date."**

Would it ultimately be best if I made them both full date values? Would that make it easier to calculate how many days apart they are?

Comment: if((row->created_date - row->delivery_date)<=21)?

Comment: If I get those bare values I don't think it's going to be able to calculate anything as the first one will return a complete datetime stamp and the second will the formatted time with slashes. If that makes sense?

Comment: `<?php if((JHTML::_('date', $row->created_date, 'd/m/Y') - $row->delivery_date)<=21) {
       echo '<span class="delivery_warning">', $row->delivery_date, '</span>';
      } else {
       echo $row->delivery_date;
      }
     ?>` - This seems to apply the span class but the issue I see here is for both fields ive got 12/34/5678. If i subtract one from the other, im not going to get a number am i? - I just want to know if I'm making sense, I'm worried of annoying people :(

Comment: I think that converting the field to a real date will be better in just about any sense: easier validation, easier calculations, easier internationalization and formatting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert Dates to a common format using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (e.g. PHP works nicely with [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)'s):

   `$created_date = strtotime($row->created_date); // These are basically seconds`
   `$deliver_date = strtotime($row->delivery_date);`
2. Calculate the difference between the two and covert it to days (each day is 86400 seconds):

   `$days = ceil(abs($deliver_date - $created_date) / 86400);`
3. Check `$days` in your `if()` statement for `echo`ing your `span`.

Something like:

```
if($days <= 21)
{
    echo '<span class="delivery_warning">' . $row->delivery_date . '</span>';
}
else
{
    else { echo $row->delivery_date; };
}
```

Comment: That worked fantastically... with just one adjustment, I had to reverse the if condition to <= (so the condition applied to a date FROM today and UPTO 21 days)

Comment: Whoops my bad, glad it helped. :D